# Hibernate4 XML mapping without POJO null pointer exceptions

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm getting a null pointer exception with the below mapping xml (without POJO).

a. employee.hmb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class entity-name="Employee"  table="employee">
    <id name="id"  column="id" type="int" >
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"  />
    <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

b. Output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:143)
at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.classForName(JavaReflectionManager.java:117)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.RevisionInfoConfiguration.configure(RevisionInfoConfiguration.java:262)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.<init>(AuditConfiguration.java:103)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.getFor(AuditConfiguration.java:166)
at org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:64)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1743)
at org.tutorial.hibernate.annotation.UserDetailDemo.main(UserDetailDemo.java:26)
```

But if i do map it to a class Employee, no issue.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you actually change when you "do map it to a class Employee", and things work?  It seems to me that that hbm.xml is already mapped to an Employee class.

Comment: @sharakan Nothing's changed. The idea is i do not want to use a class called Employee when it can all be done in the hbm.xml. It looks simple but i don't know why it gives a null pointer exception. Could it be possible hibernate4 does not allow XML mapping without POJO anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not build a Configuration which refers to classes that can't be loaded at the time that the Configuration is built.

You *can*, however, ask Hibernate to generate Java files for you, then compile them and use them at runtime.  You do this with the `hbm2java`.  There's an [Ant task](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e4821) for it, as well as some associated [IDE plugins](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#refeng_codegen).  They will generate a .java file, which you would then compile and use at runtime.

Comment: Blind me! This is ORM. Of course it needs classes. Bottomline is you still need POJO! Did i get this right?

Comment: You got it. Only question is whether you have to write it or a tool does.